# wx.TextCtrl change on mousehover

Tags: python, wxpython, wxtextctrl

I have a wxApplication with several wxTextCtrl, for example:

```
self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,pos=(100,150),size=(60,20))
self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,pos=(100,170),size=(60,20))
self.tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,pos=(100,190),size=(60,20))
self.tc_all = [self.tc1, self.tc2, self.tc3]
```

After the User entered different values and clicked on a button, I want to sort the entered values, for example the user entered this:

```
>>> values = [self.tc1.GetValue(), self.tc2.GetValue(), self.tc3.GetValue()]
>>> print values
[2,1,3]
```

I want to sort these values and change it inside the TextCtrls, so I do:

```
values.sort()
for i in range(len(values)):
    self.tc_all[i].SetValue(values[i])
```

First the values change correctly, but when I hover with the mouse on each TextCtrl, then they change back into the old value. I tried to add a *self.panel.Layout()*, but the problem still occurs.

Edit: I changed my sizer setup, now my values not even change - but I don't know what's wrong:

```
self.inputsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
for i in range(self.ticks):
    self.inputsizer.Add(self.tc_all[i], 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 2)
self.inputpanel.SetSizer(self.inputsizer)
```

and on my event (when inputs shall be sorted):

```
self.inputsizer.Layout()
```

Edit2: It's getting far from original question, don't know if I should have started a new question?!
Explanation: Somewhere in `class interpolation` I save an image ('tmp.png') which I want to display on Panel pageThree. When I don't draw any image, everything works fine. But drawing an image is important part of my program, so here two problems occur: 1) My values inside the TextCtrls "hide": Just after mousehover they appear as expected (sorted). 2) The wrong image is drawn: I get a screenshot of my panel as image at the first click on my button; when I press the button twice, the correct image is drawn.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Pyramid App",size=(800,600),pos=((wx.DisplaySize()[0]-800)/2,(wx.DisplaySize()[1]-600)/2),style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)

        self.p = wx.Panel(self,size=(800,600),pos=(0,0))
        self.p.Hide()
        self.PageThree = pageThree(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.PageThree, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()

class pageThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,size=(800,525))
        self.myparent=parent
        self.pageThree=wx.Panel(self,size=(800,525))
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.ticks = 10
        self.tc_all = [None for i in range(self.ticks)]
        self.inputsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for i in range(self.ticks):
            self.tc_all[i] = wx.TextCtrl(self.pageThree, pos=(20+10+160*(i/10),265+10+25*(i%10)),size=(80,20))
            self.inputsizer.Add(self.tc_all[i], 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 2)
        self.pageThree.SetSizer(self.inputsizer)

        self.startBtn = wx.Button(self.pageThree,label="button",pos=(350,102),size=(100,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.start, self.startBtn)

    def start(self, event):
        h = []
        for i in range(self.ticks):
            val = self.tc_all[i].GetValue()
            if not (val==''):
                h.append(float(val))
        h.sort()
        h.reverse()
        hh = h + ['']*(self.ticks-len(h))
        for i in range(self.ticks):
            self.tc_all[i].SetValue(str(hh[i]))

        self.interp = interpolation(self.myparent)
        self.interp.run(h)

    def UpdatePicture(self):
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap('tmp.png', type=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        bitmap = self.scale_bitmap(bitmap, 400, 390)
        control = wx.StaticBitmap(self.pageThree, -1, bitmap)
        control.SetPosition((350,135))

    def scale_bitmap(self, bitmap, width, height):
        image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
        image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        result = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
        return result

class interpolation():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myparent=parent
        self.page3 = pageThree(self.myparent)

    def run(self, h):
        self.page3.UpdatePicture()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I was having similar weird behavior, and it was related to my sizers.  How do you have those setup?

Comment: Just edited my question.

Comment: Can you post a stripped down version of your code so that I can try a few things?

Comment: yeah, but I'm busy now. I'll answer in some hours.

Comment: done. have a look at Edit2.

Comment: What is ```MainFrame``` supposed to do? Because here it does nothing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41909/discussion-between-munchkin-and-wnnmaw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue is with how your accessing the information, try getting at it through the sizer:

```
self.tc_all = []
for child in self.inputsizer.GetChildren():
    self.tc_all.append(child.GetWindow().GetValue())

self.tc_all = sorted(self.tc_all)

for child,item in zip(self.inputsizer.GetChildren(),self.tc_all):
    child.GetWindow().SetValue(item)

self.inputsizer.Layout()
```

So here's whats going on here.  Every sizer has children called "sizer items" (documentation [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SizerItem-class.html)) which are representations of your items on the GUI.  Calling `GetChildren()` on any sizer will return a list of all of that sizer's sizer items.  Note that these are note the items themselves, so you need to take one more step, and that is the `GetWindow()` function.  The result of `GetWindow()` on a sizer item is to return the actual item (or widget) that the sizer item represents, in the case a `TextCtrl` item.  Once you have that, you can treat is as you normally would.

***BE CAREFUL*** when using the `GetChildren()` function on a sizer that contains multiple items, as it returns **all** the children.  So your code will break if you try to call `SetValue()` on something which does not support that method, such at `StaticText`

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** The actual answer was an issue with sizers resulting from nesting panels.  Editing the sizers in the nested panel caused the strange behavior noted in the question.

Comment: thank you! But it still doesn't work. At first, in your last line it has to be *str(item)* instead of *item*. But that's not the problem. The TextCtrls still (or again) change into the old value on mouse hover.

Comment: btw: in my example *self.tc_all* is a list with all my TextCtrls, not the list with the values of them. And I get the values with a normal loop *values.append(self.tc_all[i].GetValue())* instead of using your first three lines - but this isn't the problem because in both cases we get a list with the (sorted) values of all TextCtrls.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be easier to use ```self.tc_all``` as a list of values, since you can store that as a sorted list.  In regards to your first comment, you shouldn't need ```str(item)``` since the list is of the values (which all should be strings anyways).  What type of value is it giving you?  Also, I added a line to my answer

Comment: Just wanted to say that in my example `values` is my list of values, not `self.tc_all`. I enter floats in the TextCtrls. When I add `self.inputsizer.Layout()` then my TextCtrls not even change; when I remove this line, they change but change back on mouse hover.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I rewrote my program so that I have less classes - now it works!